# How to write a Custom UItextField Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

In my app, i need to use a lot of textfields and i don't really want that every viewcontroller class contains the delegates of textfields which could be messy, I just want to create a generic class where it takes care of the delegate of textfields and returns me a text field where i can add it as a subview where ever i need. I want to make it as a library and call the class whenever i need a textfield
FOR example

```
CustomTexTField *textField = [[CustomTextField alloc] initWithFrame:Frame];
// returns  a textField whose delegate will be set to CustomTextField //
// all i should do is just adding it as a subView //
[self.view addSubView:textField];
```

Is this possible??.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Midhun Answered you need to create a custom TextField class and also set delegate in that class. Like this

.h FIle

> ```
> @interface CustomTextField : UITextField<UITextFieldDelegate>
> @end
> ```

.m File

> ```
> @implementation CustomTextField
> - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
> {
>     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
>     if (self) {
>         // Initialization code
>         self.delegate = self;
>     }
> return self;
> }
> - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
>     return YES;
> }
> - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
> }
> - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
>     return YES;
> }
> - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
> }
> - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
>     return YES;
> }
> - (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField{
>     return YES;
> }
> - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
>     return YES;
> }
> @end
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Parser I was not sure whether we should use self.delegate = self; Thanks it really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of `UITextField` and use it.

```
@interface CustomTexTField : UITextField
@end

@implementation CustomTexTField

//Add the stuffs here

@end
```

wherever you need the text field you can use:

```
CustomTexTField *textField = [[CustomTextField alloc] initWithFrame:customFrame];
[self.view addSubView:textField];
```

Comment: I have already tried the above But how can i access the delegate methods, i don't want them to be on the view controller class, will it be possible to include them in CustomTextField?. @Midhun

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with better approach using blocks:

```
class MyTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {


//MARK:- PROPERTIES

var shouldPreventAllActions:Bool = false

var canCut:Bool = true
var canCopy:Bool = true
var canPaste:Bool = true
var canSelect:Bool = true
var canSelectAll:Bool = true

var blockTextFieldShouldChangeCharactersInRangeWithReplacementString:((_ textField: UITextField, _ range: NSRange, _ string: String) -> Bool)?
var blockTextFieldShouldReturn:((_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool)?
var blockTextFieldShouldClear:((_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool)?
//MARK:-
var blockTextFieldShouldBeginEditing:((_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool)?
var blockTextFieldShouldEndEditing:((_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool)?
//MARK:-
var blockTextFieldDidBeginEditing:((_ textField: UITextField) -> Void)?
var blockTextFieldDidEndEditing:((_ textField: UITextField) -> Void)?
var blockTextFieldDidEndEditingWithReason:((_ textField: UITextField, _ reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) -> Void)?


//MARK:- INIT
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    commonInit()
}

private func commonInit(){
    // common initialization code..
}

override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    if(self.shouldPreventAllActions){
        return false
    }

    switch action {
    case #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.cut(_:)):
        return self.canCut ? super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender) : self.canCut
    case #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)):
        return self.canCopy ? super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender) : self.canCopy
    case #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)):
        return self.canPaste ? super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender) : self.canPaste
    case #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.select(_:)):
        return self.canSelect ? super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender) : self.canSelect
    case #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.selectAll(_:)):
        return self.canSelectAll ? super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender) : self.canSelectAll
    default:
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}

//MARK:- DELEGATE

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if(self.blockTextFieldShouldChangeCharactersInRangeWithReplacementString != nil){
        return self.blockTextFieldShouldChangeCharactersInRangeWithReplacementString!(textField,range,string)
    }else{
        return true
    }
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if(self.blockTextFieldShouldReturn != nil){
        return self.blockTextFieldShouldReturn!(textField)
    }else{
        return true
    }
}
func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if(self.blockTextFieldShouldClear != nil){
        return self.blockTextFieldShouldClear!(textField)
    }else{
        return true
    }
}


//MARK:-
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if(self.blockTextFieldShouldBeginEditing != nil){
        return self.blockTextFieldShouldBeginEditing!(textField)
    }else{
        return true
    }
}
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if(self.blockTextFieldShouldEndEditing != nil){
        return self.blockTextFieldShouldEndEditing!(textField)
    }else{
        return true
    }
}

//MARK:-
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if(self.blockTextFieldDidBeginEditing != nil){
        self.blockTextFieldDidBeginEditing!(textField)
    }
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if(self.blockTextFieldDidEndEditing != nil){
        self.blockTextFieldDidEndEditing!(textField)
    }
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {

    if(self.blockTextFieldDidEndEditingWithReason != nil){
        self.blockTextFieldDidEndEditingWithReason!(textField,reason)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This helped me

```
@interface CustomTextField : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate> 

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
return self;
}
```

added delegate to the customTextField class and it worked for me.

Thanks!!